# Run Insert queries upto 5 mintues MySql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Basically i have a MySql table **location**

```
------    -------------
 b_id     updated_time
------    -------------
  C1     17-5-2014 16:55:35 
  D1     17-5-2014 16:55:32
```

And another table **location_history**

```
 ------    -------------
 b_id     updated_time
------    -------------
  C1     17-5-2014 16:55:35 
  C1     17-5-2014 16:55:34
  C1     17-5-2014 16:55:33
  D1     17-5-2014 16:55:32
  D1     17-5-2014 16:55:31
  D1     17-5-2014 16:55:30
```

Here data in location table will be inserted once and keeps on updating. and then the data in location_history table keeps on inserting new record insted of update.

we can find latest updated time in Location table. For C1 it is 16:55:35 and D1 16:55:32. These insertions are RANDOM

what i want is - Based on latest updated time in location table, i want to run INSERT queries for 5 minutes in location_history table.

For suppose, I have new b_id -> E1 which has updated_time 16:55:37 in location table. So this is the latest one. Hence upto **5** minutes, INSERT queries should go on executing on my location_history table for b_id=E1

Comment: You mean you want to run continuous insert (for 5 minutes) into **location_history** after each insert into **location** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case after every insert in location table call this code (either with trigger or just a call in PHP script)

I suppose You have PHP >= 5.3.0

```
...
$check_time = time();
$up_to_time = strtotime("+ 5 minutes");

while( $check_time < $up_to_time ){

    $check_time = time();
    $updated_time = date("Y-m-d H:i", $check_time);

    // $b_id is an inserted id got from INSERT into location table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO location_history ( b_id, updated_time )
            VALUES( $b_id, '$updated_time');

    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error();
    sleep(50);

}
```